# Getting value from input checkbox without form tag 

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have pretty complicated listview component organized as table.

On every `tr` line I have one `td` with `<input type="checkbox" value="number">`. All this is within `form runat="server"` tag.

I have done check/uncheck all pretty much the same way the gmail has it. Table is reading 50 records for one page and if you check records and click `<input type="button">` it will duplicate all selected records.

What I need to know is how to read values from checked checkboxes and pass them on as JSON/serializeArray.

Thank you.

Comment: Put a little example of your source code to help us :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if they are all in a form lets say with the class `checkboxes`:

to serialize all of the checked boxes:

```
var serial = $('form.checkboxes').serialize();
```

so to put that variable lets say in a  post:

```
$.post('url', serial, function(data){ /*do something with data*/})
```

Answer (score 1):

To simply get the value of a checkbox you could use something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkBoxId').change(function () {
        var isChecked = $('#checkBoxId').val();
        //proceed as needs be
    });
});
```

This will enable you to record that a change has taken place, and further store and/or act upon the value.

As for serialization and 'passing them on', we may need more data from you. <- scratch that! @maniator just fixed that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Give the element an Id, such as:

```
<input id="checkBox1" type="checkbox" value="number" />
```

Then use JavaScript to check if it's checked:

```
var isChecked = document.getElementById("checkBox1").checked;
```

To get the value:

```
var theValue = document.getElementById("checkBox1").value;
```